# Homebrew errors in Mac OS Mavericks when trying to install scala

Tags: scala, homebrew

I just installed Mavericks and I tried `brew install scala` to install scala language but it failed.
Then I typed `brew update` but still installation of scala fails.
So I post the `brew doctor` command to help readers of stackoverflow helping me with this problem.
Here is the result :

> $ brew doctor
>
> Warning: /usr/local/etc isn't writable. This can happen
>   if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by by Homebrew.
>   If a brew tries to write a file to this directory, the install will
>   fail during the link step.
>
> You should probably `chown` /usr/local/etc
>
> Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
>   This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
>   by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
>   directories, then the install will fail during the link step. You
>   should probably `chown` them:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/share/man/man8
> ```
>
> Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew
>   directories. `./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to
>   determine if software packages are installed, and what additional
>   flags to use when compiling and linking.
>
> Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed
>   via Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew
>   provided script of the same name. We found the following "config"
>   scripts:
>
> ```
> /opt/local/bin/libpng-config
> /opt/local/bin/libpng15-config
> /opt/local/bin/ncurses5-config
> /opt/local/bin/ncursesw5-config
> /opt/local/bin/pkg-config
> /opt/local/bin/xml2-config
> ```
>
> Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:   /opt/local/bin/port
>
> This can cause trouble. You don't have to uninstall them, but you may
>   want to temporarily move them out of the way, e.g.
>
> sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports
>
> Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib. If you didn't
>   put them there on purpose they could cause problems when building
>   Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected dylibs:
>       /usr/local/lib/libicudata.49.1.2.dylib
>       /usr/local/lib/libicui18n.49.1.2.dylib
>       /usr/local/lib/libicuio.49.1.2.dylib
>       /usr/local/lib/libicule.49.1.2.dylib
>       /usr/local/lib/libiculx.49.1.2.dylib
>       /usr/local/lib/libicutest.49.1.2.dylib
>       /usr/local/lib/libicutu.49.1.2.dylib
>       /usr/local/lib/libicuuc.49.1.2.dylib
>
> Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig. If
>   you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>   building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected .pc files:
>       /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/icu-i18n.pc
>       /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/icu-io.pc
>       /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/icu-le.pc
>       /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/icu-lx.pc
>       /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/icu-uc.pc
>
> Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib. If
>   you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>   building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected static libraries:
>       /usr/local/lib/libc-client.a
>
> Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar Leaving kegs unlinked
>   can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on those kegs to
>   fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
>
> ```
> scala
> ```
>
> Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have
>   installed formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin. Consider
>   setting the PATH for example like so
>       echo export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
>
> Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
>   /opt/local/bin/pkg-config
>
> `./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
>   this other pkg-config.

brew install scala gives :

> Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed. Software
>   installed with other package managers causes known problems for
>   Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try
>   again. Warning: scala-2.10.3 already installed, it's just not linked

Comment: Did you do any of the suggested points in the `brew doctor` output? Also, what is the error when you're trying to install scala?

Comment: I updated the original post with brew install scala error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The installation went fine, it's just not providing a symbolic link to `/usr/local/bin`, because it's "afraid" of messing around with macports.

As it says in the doctor message, first change the permissions in `/usr/local/etc`:

```
chown <username> /usr/local/etc
```

probably with `sudo` prepended (`sudo chown <username> /usr/local/etc`).

Now brew can update the necessary files and link scala:

```
brew link scala
```

and you might be fine.

Comment: I am getting the following :

Comment: Warning: Could not link scala. Unlinking...
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.3... 
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

Comment: Btw scala runs fine inside intellij idea 12 ultimate, but I want to be able to run it from command line too.

Comment: You can also try with chown -R, to own files recursive.

Comment: I had to chown this one too /usr/local/share/doc

Answer (score 0):

If you still face the issue please follow the below steps:

## fix owner of files and folders recursively

sudo chown -vR $(whoami) /usr/local /opt/homebrew-cask /Library/Caches/Homebrew

## fix read/write permission of files and folders recursively

chmod -vR ug+rw /usr/local /opt/homebrew-cask /Library/Caches/Homebrew

## fix execute permission of folders recursively

find /usr/local /opt/homebrew-cask /Library/Caches/Homebrew -type d -exec chmod -v ug+x {} +

below is the link.

https://gist.github.com/stefanschmidt/047001373d1defc90b6bdd7820e92cf7

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting error while installing scala in mac os Monterey.I installed scala without homebrew with below command:

curl -fL https://github.com/coursier/launchers/raw/master/cs-x86_64-apple-darwin.gz | gzip -d > cs && chmod +x cs && (xattr -d com.apple.quarantine cs || true) && ./cs setup